# how to use key to authenticate VPN client

Tags: vpn, authentication, mikrotik

Block all the traffic in firewall filter except ports 80,443 and 3389 only over VPN PPTP. Whenever client want to connect to system behind mikrotik router they need to connect to VPN server of mikrotik router and then make RDP to system. Client need username and password that used in router's /ppp secrete to make VPN connection to VPN server.

We need this setup to avail people work from home using office Laptop. I need to generate Key instead of change password every time people want to work from home.

Right now am changing VPN password every time people take laptop to work from home. What I need is mikrotik router should generate key to authenticate VPN connection for people when they want to work from home. I'm looking whether SSH key satisfy my requirement. Suggest me the ways to make it work around.

Comment: Have you tried asking Mikrotik tech support?

Comment: I have asked same question in [mikrotik forum](forum.mikrotik.com) but no reply yet.